# Fill the area between several paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

How can the PGF library `fillbetween` be used to fill the area marked "A" in this figure? Here is the preliminary code for the figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    >=stealth'
  ]

  % Setup
% \draw [help lines] grid (8,5);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  % Axes
  \draw[name path=x-axis,->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$\tau$}] (xmax);
  \draw[name path=y-axis,->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) coordinate[label = {right:$v(\tau)$}] (ymax);

  % Value function
  \draw [blue, name path=value] (.5,4.5) .. controls (2,1)  .. (7.5,.5);

  \path [name path=level] (0,1) -- (8,1);
  \path [name intersections={of=level and value}];
    \draw[thin,gray] (0,1) node[black,left] {$\sigma$} -- (intersection-1);
    \fill[red] (intersection-1) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thin,gray,name path=taubp] (intersection-1) -- ++(0,-1) node[black,below] {$\tau^*$};

  \path [name path=levelup] (0,1.5) -- (8,1.5);
  \path [name intersections={of=levelup and value}];
    \draw[thin,gray] (0,1.5) node[black,left] {$\sigma+\epsilon$} -- (intersection-1);
    \fill[red] (intersection-1) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thin,gray,name path=taubp] (intersection-1) -- ++(0,-1.5) node[black,below] {$\tau^k$};

  \draw (2.6,1.15) node {A}; % temporary marker

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That library is part of the `pgfplots` package, I don't know if it works outside of an `axis` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I say in a comment, I'm not sure if the `fillbetween` library can be used here, but there are other options. Here is one option that uses `\clip`. Note I gave names to the intersections you found with `by={..}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,backgrounds} % added backgrounds
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
    >=stealth'
  ]

  % Setup
% \draw [help lines] grid (8,5);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  % Axes
  \draw[name path=x-axis,->] (-0.3,0) -- (8,0) coordinate[label = {below:$\tau$}] (xmax);
  \draw[name path=y-axis,->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) coordinate[label = {right:$v(\tau)$}] (ymax);

  % Value function
  \draw [blue, name path=value] (.5,4.5) .. controls (2,1)  .. (7.5,.5);

  \path [name path=level] (0,1) -- (8,1);
  \path [name intersections={of=level and value,by={lev}}];
    \draw[thin,gray] (0,1) node[black,left] {$\sigma$} -- (lev);
    \fill[red] (lev) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thin,gray,name path=taubp] (lev) -- ++(0,-1) node[black,below] {$\tau^*$};

  \path [name path=levelup] (0,1.5) -- (8,1.5);
  \path [name intersections={of=levelup and value,by={levup}}];
    \draw[thin,gray] (0,1.5) node[black,left] {$\sigma+\epsilon$} -- (levup);
    \fill[red] (levup) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thin,gray,name path=taubp] (levup) -- ++(0,-1.5) node[black,below] {$\tau^k$};

  \draw (2.6,1.15) node {A}; % temporary marker

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\clip (lev) rectangle (levup);
\fill [blue!20] (.5,4.5) .. controls (2,1)  .. (7.5,.5) |- (O) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## `pgfplots`

For fun, here is one possible method for making a diagram like this with `pgfplots` and the `fillbetween` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={f(\x)=exp(-0.5*\x+1.5)+0.5;} % some random function that looked OK
]

% for convenience, save the two x-values we want red dots at in macros
\newcommand\XTickA{2.5}
\newcommand\XTickB{4}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=center,
  xmin=-0.3,xmax=8,
  ymin=-0.3,ymax=5,
  % xtick/ytick=data means that ticks are placed at the
  % data points belonging to the first \addplot   
  xtick=data,
  ytick=data,
  typeset ticklabels with strut, % improves vertical alignment
  xticklabels={$\tau^k$,$\tau^*$},
  yticklabels={$\sigma+\epsilon$,$\sigma$},
  xlabel=$\tau$,
  ylabel=$v(\tau)$,
  domain=0.5:7.5,
  smooth
]

% because we have xtick=data,ytick=data, we first plot
% something with samples at our two x-values
% xcomb makes horizontal lines from the y-axis to the point
\addplot [xcomb, gray, samples at={\XTickA,\XTickB}] {f(x)};

% path used for lower boundary of the filled area
% if you have a compat setting lower than 1.11, you need to use
% (axis cs:x,y) for this path instead of (x,y)
\path [name path=level] (\XTickB,{f(\XTickB)}) -- (0,{f(\XTickB)});

% plot the function
\addplot [name path=value] {f(x)};

% ycomb makes vertical lines from x-axis
% add the red dots as markers
\addplot [ycomb,
          mark=*,
          mark options={red,mark size=1pt},
          gray,
          samples at={\XTickA,\XTickB}] {f(x)};

% the filling
% use soft clip to limit the domain of the filling
% I had to use a value slightly higher than 4.0 to get the
% correct filling, possibly due to some roundoff error.
\addplot [blue!10] fill between[of=value and level,
                                soft clip={domain=2.5:4.01}
                               ];

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! For the TikZ solution, the "value" path is specified twice — once to draw the curve, and once for the fill. Is there a way to reuse the path that was defined the first time?

Comment: @Michael I don't know.